# How to add a unique field to every document in a project in aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is my project query.

```
$project:
                {
                    color:1,
                    status:1,
                    message:1,
                    created:1,
                    announcementId:1,
                    by: "$by.name",
                    for: "$for.name",
                    byId: "$by.userId",
                    forId: "$for.userId",
                    index: // this is where I need an incrementing value
                }
```

I want to add a unique value to the index property. Is it possible to use $$CURRENT to get the current index? Or use an external variable with an incrementing value?

Comment: how many documents do you've in your collection & what is size of your collection ?

Comment: Those keep on changing.

Comment: idea here is we can do it only if data set size is low..

Comment: `_id` is already unique